# Simple Injector - Register Compared to Bind in Ninject

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ninject, simple-injector

I'm trying to register the following equivalent in Ninject but I'm having difficulty (partly because of all the changes/deprecation from earlier versions of Simple Injector).   Can someone please confirm how the following bindings would be translated to Simple Injector?

```
this.kernel.Bind(x => x.FromThisAssembly()
                   .SelectAllClasses().InheritedFrom<MyFactory>().BindToSelf()
                   .Configure(b => b.InSingletonScope()));


this.kernel.Bind(x => x.FromThisAssembly()
                   .SelectAllClasses()
                   .InNamespaceOf<MyClass>().BindToSelf()
                   .Configure(b => b.InSingletonScope()));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
container.RegisterCollection(typeof(MyFactory), Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

var namespaceTypes =
    from type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
    where type.Namespace == typeof(MyClass).Namespace
    select type;

foreach (Type type in namespaceTypes)
    container.Register(type, type, Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

Comment: Thank you.   I had several close variations of these but they were not quite right.  These are what I need.